# Im getting this problem with a api im using to show how many subs i have on youtube

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command(aliases=["subscribers"])
async def subs(ctx):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCG0OvtYX4qA6Ap1OxQpohOA&key=key") as response:
      subscriberCount = (await response.json())["items[0].statistics.subscriberCount"]
      await ctx.send(f"THE PLAYER ZER0 is currently at {subscriberCount} subscribers!")
      await session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem

```py
subscriberCount = (await response.json())["items[0].statistics.subscriberCount"]
```

Try this:

```py
subscriberCount = (await response.json()).items[0].statistics.subscriberCount
```